# Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' + Spring Boot + Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven

I have a few problems starting up the spring guide on how to access mysql data (see this link: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/). I adjusted the classes slightly, so I have this code:

1. **pom.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>gs-mysql-data</artifactId>
       <version>0.1.0</version>

       <parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
   </parent>

   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

   <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

I am using this mainController:
**MainController.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.resource.iPbackend.UserRepository;
import com.resource.iPbackend.User;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/main")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/reg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String regNewUser (@RequestParam String firstName,      @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password, @RequestParam String username) {
        User n = new User();
        n.setFirstName(firstName);
        n.setLastName(lastName);
        n.setEmail(email);
        n.setPassword(password);
        n.setUsername(username);
        userRepository.save(n);
        return "User is stored in database: " + n;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Together with this repository:
**UserRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.resource.iPbackend.User;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

And this Entity:
**User.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String username;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

And finally I have this Application.class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class IPbackendApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(IPbackendApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

I am getting this error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The relevant code is missing: Where is your DB configuration for as used by spring?

Answer (score 9):

Look at this message in the exception trace :

> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **URL must start with 'jdbc'** at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)

You very probably don't provide an `application.properties` file that values the `spring.datasource.url` property.
Or else you don't value it correctly.

It should look like :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
```

You can refer to [the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html).

Answer (score 3):

I received pretty similar error when try to test my dao layer.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class ItemRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Test
    public void findAll() {
        List<Item> allItems = itemRepository.findAll();
        Assertions.assertThat(allItems).hasSize(9);
    }
}
```

The issue was resolved by adding:

> @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)

to the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class ItemRepositoryTest {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last properties that you share have some errors to fix `spring.datasource.data-username=myuser` and `spring.datasource.data-password=ThePassword`

This is and example of how to properly configure the spring datasource

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

It is another example from [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```